# Interpretation of an article - Bessel function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, bessel-functions

I'm trying to reproduce [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EuWFA9czuP3axS1XqMTfJvScoE9Sug_s/view?usp=sharing) article findings, which is being shared in google drive.

It treats the problem of describing a sessile and pendant drop curve by solving an ODE numerically, with *fourth-order Runge-Kutta* method.

The article has some notation which confused me quite a bit. So, I came to this forum seeking for advice.

This notation is in page 5, but I'm sharing it bellow:
[image]

The confusion arrises because the authors use notation *$I_0$* and defines it as the Bessel function of the second kind.

However, using Wikipedia as a reference, the Bessel function of the second kind is commonly referred as *$Y_n$* or even *$K_n$* if we are talking about the modified version.

[image]

I finish this topic asking you for help. What Bessel function should I considered when trying to reproduce  the authors findings, based on the Wikipedia notation?

PS: Considering this is not a conventional post in this forums, please feel free to comment any other additional information and considerations regarding the organization of the post.